# The specified module (mod_h264_streaming) could not be found (Apache2)?

Tags: apache-http-server, streaming, h.264

I'm trying to get the mod_h264_streaming to work with my Apache2 server. I downloaded a precompiled version of the mod from [here](http://h264.code-shop.com/download//apache_mod_h264_streaming-2.2.7.zip). I read [here](http://blog.codingmafia.com/?p=167) that all I have to do is extract the file to my modules folder, which I did, and add

```
LoadModule h264_streaming_module modules/mod_h264_streaming.so
AddHandler h264-streaming.extensions .mp4
```

to the httpd.conf, which I also did. However, I get this error when I restart Apache:

```
Syntax error on line 173 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Group/Apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
Cannot load C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Group/Apache2/modules/mod_h264_streaming.so into server: The specified module could not be found.
Note the errors or messages above, and press the <ESC> key to exit.  26...
```

Even though the file exists right here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\modules\mod_h264_streaming.so
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It probably requires some other file that you don't have. If you have a [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), point it at the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the name of your Apache installation's directory I assume that you're running Apache 2.0.x. This plugin seems to be broken when being ran on 2.0 branch. The documentation says it's minimal version requirement is 2.0.55 as stated [here](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/ReleaseNotes-Version2#a2010-01Version2.2.7), but I was not able to run this module at all with 2.0.64 from [this official mirror](http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/apache//httpd/binaries/win32/).

I was successful in running that plugin with 2.2.22 (from the same mirror). Can you upgrade the Apache version?